# Search Bar with Location dropdown sumit both results - PHP / mySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, search, keyword

I have a basic search bar that searches my database using keywords (k). I am trying to submit both location and search result but the problem is when I submit the search results I get `"search.php?k=builder&k=New+York"` and not `"search.php?k=builder+New+York"` how do I correct this?

HTML

```
<form action="search.php" method="get" style="margin:0 auto; text-align:center;">
    <input type="text" name="k" size="10" style="width:40%;"/>

    <div id="the-basics">
    <input class="typeahead" type="text" name="k" placeholder="States of USA">
        </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Search" style="width:100px;">
</form>
```

Search Bar PHP Code:

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_GET['k'])){
        //if search bar is empty
    }else{
       echo "'<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=index.php'>";
       //redirect back to index.php
    }
    $k = $_GET['k']; //k stands for keyword

    $i = 0;
    $terms = explode(" ", $k);
    $query ="SELECT * FROM record WHERE ";

    foreach ($terms as $each) {
        $i++;
        if ($i == 1)
            $query .= "company_name LIKE '%$each%' " . "OR website LIKE '%$each%' " . "OR email LIKE '%$each%' " . "OR tel LIKE '%$each%' " . "OR  description LIKE '%$each%'" . "OR  location LIKE '%$each%'" . "OR  description LIKE '%$each%'";

    }

    $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
    mysql_select_db('DB_name');



    $query = mysql_query($query);
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if ($numrows > 0){

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { { ?>
        ..........search result shows here........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you need appaly some JS

```
<script>
function submitForm(obj){
          var search =  $('input[name="k"]).val();
 var state=  $('#state').val();
 $('input[name="k"]).val(search+" "+state )
obj.submit();
}
</script>

<form action="search.php" method="get" style="margin:0 auto; text-align:center;" onsubmit=submitForm(this)>
    <input type="text" name="k" size="10" style="width:40%;"/>

    <div id="the-basics">
    <input class="typeahead" type="text" id="state" placeholder="States of USA">
        </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Search" style="width:100px;">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried the code and it did work so I had to change it a little. https://jsfiddle.net/pd16f868/ the url now displays "search.php?k=builder+Illinois&state=Illinois" is this correct.